# Multiple process accessing single table for insert

Tags: c, oracle

I have a TABLE (PROCESSED_RECS) which is accessed by multiple processes (around 60). All of them insert recs in this file.

Purpose:

- Processes take an input file of keys to process
- they check if keys is already process - i.e. in table PROCESSED_RECS
- To check, processes just fire INSERT query
- if they get DUPLICATE ERROR freom Oracle, they get to know it is already processed.

But i am getting error

> ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

What is the best practice for achieving above scenario ?

I am using `PRO C` with `C` language

Comment: What other options have you tried? Have you researched the different locking options available in Oracle?

Comment: What does the deadlock trace file say?  Are multiple processes processing the same key at the same time?  Are you processing keys in any order?

Comment: @JustinCave No there isn't any order for keys which app uses

Comment: @Bigwave I checked .. people say Oracle does not lock if primary keys are dropped... but i can't do that

Comment: @SimpleGuy You definitely want to look for the trace file, like Justin suggested.  It will tell you which objects are causing the deadlock - it could be the table (unlikely but possible), a bitmap index, a table with an un-indexed foreign key, etc.  In general deadlocks should not occur from multiple inserts, unless something weird is happening.

Comment: could it be a good idea to commit after a succesfull insert and rollback after a non-succesfull? [oracle's explenation](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_parallel_dml_deadlock_detected.htm)

Comment: the code could use a named mutex, visible to all processes.  use that mutex to only allow a single process to 1) pend on locking mutex  2) try to read the current key from data base  3) if read fails write new key record, 4) finally, unlock mutex.

Comment: @SimpleGuy Oracle does lock on all inserts, dropping the primary key just allows you to insert multiple records with identical values

Comment: "best practice" is a term which only applies to common problems in well-understood domains.  Your scenario is highly unusual so there can be no best practice.  If you explain your  actual *requirement* we might be able to offer a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a single process reading the keys from file and storing them in a queue (AQ). The 60 processes can safely enqueue the keys and do not  need to perform any check if the key was processed or not.
It is not possible that two processes will get the same key. Event if a process fails, it will rollback and an other process may resume with the key.

Generell best practice is, that SQL is not very good for DIY queueing implementations.